# How to rename classes with exports?

Tags: dart

I would like to make packages that do nothing besides exporting a few classes of another library under a different name.

In javascript I could do the following:

```
export { foo as bar } from 'package'
```

But I haven't found anything similar in dart

Comment: What I truly want is to rename things like CupertinoDialog/CupertinoScaffold of flutter to Dialog/Scaffold. I could then import material/cupertino components using `import '...' as material` to ultimately do `material.Dialog`/`cupertino.Dialog`

Comment: This link points to this question ;-)

Comment: What a fail :p https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/2626

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing in Dart.

Imports allow only to show or hide members of the imported library or specify an import prefix.

I can imagine that `typedef`s will be extended to do that eventually.

What you can do is to create subclasses

```
class Dialog extends CupertinoDialog {}
```

and in another library

```
class Dialog extends MaterialDialog {}
```

Conditional imports might be extended at some point to allow importing one or the other library depending on some condition (probably only build-time setting).
Currently it only allows to distinguish platforms like web, server, Flutter as far as I know.

Comment: For the "conditional import" part, I use different main.dart. It does the job fairly decently for now, without loosing tree-shaking